# Mix ada with assembly

Tags: ada

How I can mix Ada code with assembly (assembled using GAS)?

I know how to link Ada with C, but how I can link with assembly? I know that gcc generates assembly code from Ada code, and because of this, I think is possible to do this cross-linking.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Inline-Assembler.html

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you would compile the assembly into a .o object file and give this as a parameter to your Ada compiler.

Comment: Also have to match calling and naming conventions.

Comment: but how can I work with the two codes?
For example, I write code in assembly to the sum of two numbers, and the program in Ada who will send the numbers for the assembly code and the assembly code returns the value added.

Comment: @Alexandre I hope this doesn't go into an application anyone uses. I wouldn't want anyone to write assembly in an ADA project other than for educating oneself. For simple problems like addition, use the inline assembler. But be aware that if you don't know what you're doing, you can break things. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Inlining-Inline-Assembler-Code.html#Inlining-Inline-Assembler-Code

Comment: The contents of certain registers must not be touched http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf and you can really break things when you fiddle with interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I work with the two codes?

If you are using [GNAT](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnat/) on Intel x86, the [Inline Assembler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Inline-Assembler.html#Inline-Assembler) includes related examples.

Addendum: The `-S` option allows one "to examine the generated assembly code." This applies to Ada, C, C++, etc.

Comment: Hi, but, if I need to use separate files, the specific file of assembly and specific file for Ada code, link mix C with C++.

Comment: Yes, as noted by @whoplisp. AFAIK, the linker doesn't know (or care) how the `.o` was generated. Use the `-S` option to see the intermediate assembly listing of compiled sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform any kind of mixed-language programming with Ada, including Ada/Assember, you should probably look at your compiler's documentation on [Interfacing pragmas](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-1.html), in particular its allowed calling conventions.

For example, [Gnat provides an `Assembler` convention](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Calling-Conventions.html) for `pragma import`/`export`.

Generally you will have to craft your assembler to act as a subprogram which uses a calling convention compatible with the "convention" used in your interfacing pragma.

Most compilers also support some kind of inline assembly, via the [System.Machine_Code](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-8.html) package. This allows you to mix small amounts of assembly language right in the same source files with your Ada.